# Converting Front Hand View to Back Hand View or vice versa Using Python

Tags: python, image, rgb, mediapipe, 3d-reconstruction

I'm working on a hand pose estimation project where I've successfully used Google's MediaPipe to extract the hand skeleton from images of the front view of hands. I'm looking for a way to convert or simulate the back view of the hand based on this skeleton data.

My goal is to simulate or calculate the back view of the hand using the skeleton data obtained from the front view or using an image. This could be for visualization purposes or further analysis. It can be the front side of the hand or the back side of the hand and we get the other side of the hand.

1. Is there a known method or algorithm that allows for such a transformation using the skeletal data?
2. Would I need to apply specific transformations or rotations to the key points to achieve a backhand view simulation?
3. Any advice or pointers to resources that could help with this kind of task would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77979422/how-to-generate-3d-hand-mesh-from-2d-skeleton-image-or-real-hand-using-python